# Value error when training model with randomforest classifier

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest

```
from sklearn import ensemble
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
import time
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
enc = preprocessing.OneHotEncoder()
onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(categories='auto')
enc.fit(X)
onehotlabels = enc.transform(X).toarray()
onehotlabels.shape
clf=RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=10)
clf.fit(X_train,y_train)
y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)
print("Accuracy:",metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))
predict = clf.predict(X_test)
print("Evaluation on Test Set",predict)
```

I am doing this to train my model with randomforest classifier. I am getting the following error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'gorilla'
```

Comment: this doesn’t give context to the error. Copy and paste the error you’re getting with it’s trace back

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell for sure by looking at your code, because data structures of X, X_train or X_test is not clear.
However, I suspect that the `onehotlabels` variable is not used.
If one hot encoding worked properly, 'gorilla' string would not have been included.

So, I suggest that you check whether the following code had been executed.

```
X_train, X_test = train_test_split(onehotlabels)
```